# java athletes score average calculator

Tags: java

I am trying to create a java program that calculates the average score of a team of n athletes. Each athlete has 3 scores.

1) Create an athlete class with the following fields:

- name
- array of 3 scores
- setters and getters (they must have the score number as argument.)
- a constructor that clears the data
  2) another class that has:

  - an array of athletes.

Note: the user operations to perform:

- add an athlete. the user can add athletes without scores and add scores later.
- add scores (the user must be prompt to enter the score number then add scores for all athlete for that score.)

Here is my code.

```
package demo;

public class Athlete {
    private String name;

    private int[] scores = new scores[3];

    Athlete(){
        this.name = "";

        this.scores= new int[]{-1.0, -1.0, -1.0};
    }

    Athlete(String name, int[] scores){
        this.name=name;
        this.scores[0]= getscores(1);
        this.scores[1]= getscores(2);
        this.scores[2]= getscores(3);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setscores(int scores, int scoresNumber){
        grades[scoresNumber-1] = scores;
    }

    public int getscores(int scoresNumber){
        return  grades[scoresNumber-1];
    }

    public int[] getscores(){
        scores[0]= getscores(1);
        scores[1] = getscores(2);
        scores[2] = getscores(3);
        return  scores;
    }
}
```

//In this test, I am just testing for one athlete

My driver class is

```
package demo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AthleteDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Athlete d = new Athlete();
    String name;
    int scoresNumber;
    int score;

    System.out.println("Name ");
    name = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Score number ");
    scoresNumber = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("score ");
    score = sc.nextInt();
    d.setscoreGrades(score, scoresNumber);
    System.out.println(d.getscores(scoresNumber));

   System.out.println(d.getscores();
}
```

My problem is that I can't print out the array of scores. `d.getscores()` gives me a reference value.

So how am I able to print out the array of scores?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Comment: Have you actually tried to run this code? It is full of compilation errors. I would fix those first before asking a question here.

Comment: where do grades[] come from? I didnt see it declared in the Athelete class

Comment: @bajada93  considering OP has mentioned his/hers current code displays the reference of the array rather than its contents that could potentially mean it's compiling fine.

Comment: @jobethbillien considering OP has mentioned his/hers current code is displaying the reference of the array rather than its contents that could potentially mean it's compiling fine hence he/she probably didn't include that array within the provided code.

Answer (score 0):

> my problem is that I can't print out the array of scores d.getscores()
>   it gives me a reference value

use [**Arrays.toString(type[ ] a)**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), which returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.

**note** - this method is overloaded so it should work for most types (if not all).

> So how am I able to print out the array of scores?

*replace this:*

```
System.out.println(d.getscores());
```

*with this:*

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(d.getscores()));
```

Comment: Okay. I see . Thank you so much.

Comment: @SoulbeYeo you're welcome, don't forget to mark answer as accepted it if has solved your problem. :).